rowSelection event does not provide _children data in lightning-tree-grid
I am trying to get the child row data on the "onrowselection" custom event. I log event.detail to find that it provides everything EXCEPT the children rows, and only has "hasChildren:true" property.
How can I get the ACTUAL data(with children) from this event?
HTML
<lightning-tree-grid
            class="results"
            data-id="gridResult"
            columns={gridColumns}
            data={treeGridData}
            key-field="relationshipId"
            expanded-rows={expandedRows}
            selected-rows={selectedRows}
            **onrowselection={setSelectedRows}**>
</lightning-tree-grid>

JS
setSelectedRows(event) {
        console.log("EVENT DETAIL" + JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        switch (event.detail.config.action) {
            case "rowSelect":
                this.handleRowSelect()
                break......

CONSOLE LOG


When a row is selected, the event.detail.selectedRows property contains the selected row data. Since the onrowselection event only indicates that the row has children (with hasChildren: true), you need to fetch the child rows manually. You can do this by querying the data source again based on the selected row's ID.
Example:
setSelectedRows(event) {
    console.log("EVENT DETAIL: " + JSON.stringify(event.detail));
    const selectedRow = event.detail.selectedRows[0]; // Assuming single row selection

    if (selectedRow.hasChildren) {
        this.fetchChildRows(selectedRow.relationshipId).then(childRows => {
            console.log("Child Rows: ", childRows);
            // You can now process the child rows as needed
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching child rows: ", error);
        });
    }
}

fetchChildRows(parentId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const childRows = this.treeGridData.filter(row => row.parentId === parentId);
        if (childRows.length > 0) {
            resolve(childRows);
        } else {
            reject("No child rows found");
        }
    });
}


This does get the children, however i did implement a different solution to my problem. My goal is to hide nested columns but this provides a whole seperate challenge as the table uses the keyfield contactID) to expand/select/etc...I want to use contactId as key field but i dont want to show it on the nested rows. The only way i know currently is to just not include it with the children data. ( But this mainly answers my question: IE "No onrowselection does not provide the children in any way as of now". Thank you!
